# Debugging multiple executions of a same project in ms visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I need to run the Visual C++ (2012 pro) remote debugger for multiple processes of a windows driver application.

In the solution property page there’s an option to select multiple startup projects. Is there any similar option to run the remote debugger on multiple executions of a *same* project?